# Deploying local elasticsearch cluster on azure

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Apache Nutch to crawl sites for one of my project. The data and the content is successfully crawled. For indexing and search queries, I am using Elasticsearch clusters to process data easily. I am really new to Elasticsearch clusters, locally everything is working fine. But now I want to deploy the same local clusters on Azure services so I can communicate with data from another application that I am working on. I have seen some tutorials, but there is no option of deploying your local clusters on Azure.

Please guide me through this.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not deploy local cluster on azure, you need to setup another es cluster on azure nodes & point your writing application to that cluster.